# Pass down expression without evaluating it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to pass down an expression that will be evaluated inside my directive template from a parent directive attribute.

In this case it will be something like this. My "expression" attribute will be mapped to my templates anchors ngHref attribute without any evaluation done by the parent.

Here's a example of what i want to do.

```
<div data-my-directive data-expression="'#/inventory/{{page}}'"> </div>
```

HTML TEMPLATE (DIRECTIVE TEMPLATE)

```
<ul>
   <li data-ng-repeat="page in pageNumberCol"> 
       <a data-ng-href="{{expression}}">Page {{page}}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

DIRECTIVE DECLARATION

```
    app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
         templateUrl: "/app/directivelayout/myDirectiveTemplate.html"
        , scope: {

           expression: "=?" // What binding do i do here???? @ & or =
        }
    } });
```

RENDERED HTML

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#/inventory/1"> page1 </a> </li>
   <li><a href="#/inventory/2"> page2 </a> </li>
   <li><a href="#/inventory/3"> page3 </a> </li>
</ul>
```

---

UPDATE: I have figured out a solution but i don't like too much, so if you have something for me I'm still open to an alternate solution.

Instead of an expression i pass in a function that takes in the page number and returns the generated link.

So in my template anchors i would do something like this.

```
  <li data-ng-repeat="page in pageNumColl >
     <a data-ng-href="{{generateLink(page)}}" >  Page {{page }} </a>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set up your passing slightly differently

```
<div data-my-directive exp="'#/inventory/' + page"> </div>
```

Then in the directive

```
    scope: {
        exp: "=",
    },
```

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QbggX/) that does basically this, it gives you the output:

```
<a href="test/1" exp="'test/' + page" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-binding">test/1</a>
```

Hope this helps!